# Ionic Web API Audio() on iOS when screen is locked

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, audio, ionic-framework

I'm having a problem with Ionic using the javascript Web API Audio(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement) element on iOS 8.

I have many mp3 files hosted on a server and I play them using the Audio element like this:

```
player = Audio(url)
player.play()
```

The file plays fine and it doesn't wait until the file is downloaded to play it (it plays it as it goes).

The problem is that when the screen is locked, it shows the URL of the file I'm playing, which I don't want.

So, basically the question is:

How I can hide that URL when I'm playing a file and the screen is locked?

My config:

```
Cordova CLI: 5.4.1
Gulp version:  CLI version 3.8.11
Gulp local:  
Ionic CLI Version: 1.7.12
Ionic App Lib Version: 0.6.5
ios-deploy version: 1.8.3 
ios-sim version: 5.0.4 
OS: Mac OS X El Capitan
Node Version: v4.2.3
Xcode version: Xcode 7.1.1 Build version 7B1005
```

PS: The only reason im using the Web API instead of the cordova-plugin-media (https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media) is because on iOS the player needs to download the entire mp3 file before playing it (it does not works as pseudo streaming) like on Android, which plays the file as it downloads it.

Answer (score -1):

you can save the audio src to localstorage and set the audio src to "#" when get screen locked

Comment: Then it will cease playing. Use Cordova-music-controls.